# Function Loads on terminal instead of after loading tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

```
enter code here
    def validator ():

    if desAddress.get()=='' and sourceAddress.get()=='' :
        messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the source address \n Enter destination address')
    elif sourceAddress.get()=='':
         messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the source address')
    elif desAddress.get()=='':
         messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the destination address')
    def exe():
 os.system('python class_runner.py')
 funVariable=lambda:validator(),exe()

enter code here
```

The above code is giving me serious headache. my funVariable loads on the terminal instead of loading after clicking the button preventing my tkinter window from loading.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.  the issue with the code was that I was importing the .py file at the top which was preventing the code from running. resolved.